# In Swift: How to populate the next available Table View cell with the contents of a Text Field?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a ViewController.swift and a TableViewCell.swift file. In the main storyboard, I have a basic View Controller with a Text Field at the top, and a Table View underneath. I have a Prototype Cell within the Table View and its identifier is "cell" and class is "TableViewCell".

I want the user to tap on the Text Field, enter a String, and click Return on the keypad. Then I want that String to be pasted into the next available Table View Cell (each time this happens the next cell lower should populate).

Above and beyond the basic code that the files already have, I have the following:

In ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let textFromField = textField.text
    cell.textLabel!.text = textFromField
    return cell }
```

Comment: You need an array that provides the data to the tableview. Each time you add a new value, add it to the array and insert the new row into the tableview.

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable that is an array of String

```
var array = [String]
```

Then you need to append the text value of the textfield to the array

```
array.append(textField.text)
```

Then in your datasource you need to return the number of sections (seemingly 1 in your case) and the number of rows in the section

```
array.count
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath you need to return each of the items in the array

```
let item = array[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel.text = item
return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand. You should use `delegate`.

1. Caculate `rowWillFill` by `indexPath.row` you want to fill.
2. TableViewCell implement delegate.

   if ( cell_index = indexPath.row )
   {

   ```
   rowWillFill += 1

   tableViewCell.textLabel.text = String
   ```

   }
3. Then update cell by `tableView.updateCellAtIndexPath`
   GoodLuck!